# codeigniter 2.1.0 Routing difficulties

Tags: codeigniter-2

I can not load controller with

```
http://localhost/index.php?controller/method
```

But if i does not use '?' and try to load a controller from view then duplicate URL produce.
As an example of above, if i add this link in form action in view then result url will be

```
http://localhost/index.php/controller/index.php/controller/method
```

How to solve it? I did not use htaccess file

Comment: Do you have your base_url() set in config.php?

Comment: yes it did. it should be http://localhost/codeigniter_folder_name right?

Comment: does http://localhost/index.php/controller/method work?

Comment: yes it works. But if i set it in form action it call index.php/controller/index.php/controller/method . and '?' is not working

Comment: does you form open look like this: `form_open('controller/method');`

Comment: i did not change any default settings excluding (default route, base url, database)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `site_url()` function or, as @JohnFable stated, use the `form_open` function.

```
<form method="post" action="<?= form_open('controller/method'); ?>">
```

or

```
<a href="<?= site_url('controller/method'); ?>">Controller/Method</a>
```

or

```
<?= form_open('controller/method'); ?>
```

This will ensure that your "base url", i.e. `http://localhost` is prepended correctly to the URL you want to view, i.e. `http://localhost/index.php/controller/method` or if you have set it up to, `http://localhost/controller/method`

Gavin